# define a grammar in Antlr

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I have defined the following grammar.

```
grammar Sample_1;


@header {
  package a;
}

@lexer::header {
  package a;
}

program
    :   
        define*
        implement*
    ;


define
    :   IDENT '=(' INTEGER',' INTEGER ')'
    ;

implement
    :IDENT '=(' (IDENT ','?)* ')'
    ;

fragment LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ;
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
INTEGER : DIGIT+ ;
IDENT : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*;
WS : (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' | '\f')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;};
COMMENT : '//' .* ('\n'|'\r') {$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

How to check in this grammar so that when I have the example

```
A=(1,1)
B=(1,2)

G=(A,B)
```

the result is successful but if I write

```
A=(1,1)
B=(1,2)

G=(A,E)
```

it gives an error that E is not defined
thanks

the result:
i got it working thanks a lot:

```
grammar Sample_1;

@members{
    int level=0;
}

@header {
  package a;
}

@lexer::header {
  package a;
}

program
    :   
        block
    ;
block   
scope {
    List symbols;
}
@init {
    $block::symbols=new ArrayList();
    level++;
}
@after { 
     System.err.println("Hello");
     level--;
 }
    : (define* implement+)
    ;

define
    :   IDENT {$block::symbols.add($IDENT.text);} '=(' INTEGER',' INTEGER ')' 
    ;

implement
    :IDENT '=(' (a=IDENT 
    {if (!$block::symbols.contains($a.text)){
    System.err.println("undefined");
    }}','?)* ')'
    ;

fragment LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ;
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
INTEGER : DIGIT+ ;
IDENT : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*;
WS : (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' | '\f')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;};
COMMENT : '//' .* ('\n'|'\r') {$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

Comment: So, in other words, evaluation of the grammar depends on context?

Comment: yes, im not sure how difficult is this to implement

Comment: Is it also allowed to write `H=(A,3)`?

Comment: No in the implementation only the defined parts in define should be included, no other language symbols

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antlr supports *actions*, little snippets of code embedded in the grammar file.

An action for an assignment could store into a map. An action for a right-hand-side IDENT could try to pull a value from the map, and throw an exception if it fails.

Chapter 6 in Terrence Parr's "The Definitive ANTLR Reference" covers actions.

Comment: +1. Clarification, from http://www.antlr.org/doc/glossary.html#Context-sensitive: "In an ANTLR sense, you can recognize context-sensitive constructs with a semantic predicate. The action evaluates to true or false indicating the validity of applying the alternative."

Comment: I did look at the book: and could do the following, but having dif going further:                                                @members{
 Map symbols= new HashMap();
}
  
program
 : 
  define*
  implement*
 ;

define
 : a=IDENT {symbols.put($a);} '=(' INTEGER',' INTEGER ')' 
 ;
 
implement
 :IDENT '=(' (IDENT ','?)* ')'
 ;